# SQL Queries within PHP Scripts

Tags: php, sql

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have a database that consists of 3 tables.

1. **user**: 4 columns userId [primary key], name, emailId, password
2. **residentController**: 3 columns userId [foreign], departmentId [foreign], checkDefault
   `checkDefault` will be set to 1.
3. **department** with 6 columns: departmentId [primaryKey], departmentName, departmentDesc, departmentLink, checkDefault, departmentCategory

Here is the sequence that follows when a user registers for an android application. The following php script will be called.

It will add a record of the user into the database. After insertion of the data in the `user` table, I want to get all the  "departmentNames" from `department` table and insert it into `residentController`. In the end, after particular user registers, then residentController must have these values populated into the residentController table.

```
userId  departmentId checkDefault
---------------------------------
1          1             1      
1          2             1      
1          3             1      
1          4             1      
1          5             1
```

Here is my php script.

```
<?php
require "init.php";
$fullname = "Fahman Khan";//$_POST["user"];
$emailid = "fxk120@hotmail.com";//$_POST["user_name"];
$userpass = "Windows";//$_POST["user_pass"];
$sql_query = "insert into user values(NULL,'$fullname','$emailid','$userpass')";
if(mysqli_query($connection, $sql_query))
{
echo "<h2> Data insertion success</h2>";
//Get the user id of the the registered user
$sql_queryTwo = "SELECT userId FROM user WHERE emailId='".$emailid."'";
//Store the result of the query in a variable
$result= mysqli_query($connection,$sql_queryTwo);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
//Retrive the user id
$data = $row[0];

//Insert default departments into residentController
}
else
{
//echo "Data insertion error".mysqli_error($connection);
}
?>
```

My question is that in my current php script, I don't know how I can insert departmentID into residentController table. departmentId is a foreign key and in my current department table there are 5 departments. I just need help writing the part in my php where I can insert in values into my residentController table. As of now, the current php script only adds a new user, but I need help inserting values into my residentController table.

Comment: what is your question exactly? Also errors you get.

Comment: My question is that in my current php script, I don't know how I can insert departmentID into `residentController` table. departmentId is a foreign key and in my current `department` table there are 5 departments. I just need help writing the part in my php where I can insert in values into my `residentController` table. As of now, the current php script only adds a new user, but I need help inserting values into my `residentController` table.